# how to delete nested json element by variable

Tags: json

how to delete a particular json element by variable:
i.e. I want to delete obj.a.b, but it is passed by a variable.
Is there a simple way to implement this?

```js
var t = 'obj.a.b';
var obj = {a: {b: 'b', b2: 'b2'}};
delete t;  // not work here
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust the value of `t`, you can use the `eval(...)` function to execute dynamic code like this:

```js
var t = 'obj.a.b';
var obj = {a: {b: 'b', b2: 'b2'}};
eval("delete " + t + ";");
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Note that if you cannot trust the value of `t` (e.g. it's a user-supplied value), an attacker can inject code by supplying a malicious value for `t`. You have to use `eval(...)` carefully as it can easily lead to such code-injection attack.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) has good discussion about how and when to use eval.